# Centralizer of the derived algebra in a non-perfect Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Is there a non-perfect Lie algebra for which the centralizer of the derived algebra is trivial?

Comment: (Assuming things to be finite-dimensional over a field of char zero.) This has to be a non-solvable, non-perfect Lie algebra, with trivial center (hence non-reductive). The unique smallest such algebra is indeed $\mathfrak{gl}_2(K)\ltimes K^2$, as in Dave's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for $n \ge 2$, the derived algebra of the semidirect product $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R}) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R}) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$, and this has trivial centralizer.